# Why is my program crashing at this one line?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class myset{
private:
    T *pArray;
    int size;

public:
    myset<T>(){
        pArray = new T[0];
        int size =0;
    }

    void addItem(T iVal){
        size++;
        T* newArray = new T [size];// allocate bigger array //
        for(int i=0; i< size-1; i++){
            newArray[i] = pArray[i]; // IT IS CRASHING BECAUSE OF THIS LINE
        }
        pArray[size -1] = iVal;
        pArray = NULL;
        pArray = newArray;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myset<int> a;
    myset<double> d;
    a.addItem(3);
    a.addItem(5);
}
```

What I am trying to do is making a dynamic array of any template. In my add function, I am trying to copy my old array into my new array. Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: Why are you shadowing your class's `size var in the ctor?

Comment: What did you discover when you used the debugger?

Comment: *What I am trying to do is making a dynamic array of any template* -- What's wrong with just using `std::vector<your_type>`?

Comment: you are not even deleting already allocated objects, using NULL instead of nullptr and int instead of size_t.

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor, `int size =0;` is declaring and initialising a new local variable named `size`. It isn't initialising the member variable `myset::size`. This means when `myset` is constructed, `myset::size` will contain garbage. I.e. It could start at any value.

Also, in `addItem`, you add the item to the old array rather than the new one, and then discard the pointer to that array without freeing its memory, which causes a memory leak and the new array to contain nothing but garbage.